# error when build the jar in mongo-hadoop using $ ./gradlew jar command

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, jar

I have cloned the mongo-hadoop connector git repository using the below reference,

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/

After successful cloning while i am trying to build jar using $ ./gradlew jar its showing following exception,

```
 hduser@mypc:/mongo-hadoop$ ./gradlew jar
:compileJava
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess using    TaskExecutionServices.createCacheAccess().
> Failed to create parent directory '/mongo-hadoop/.gradle' when creating directory '/mongo-hadoop/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info   or --debug option to get more log output.
```

BUILD FAILED

What will be the reason for this could any one help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: It failed to create a directory - could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: After using sudo its get solved. Thanks for the info

Comment: Sudo is not the final solution. Set GRADLE_USER_HOME=<to_some_folder_where_you_have_valid_rwx_access>/.gradle and it'll work. For ex: set value to ~/.gradle